# Is there a way to automatically assign new users a disk quota limit as they are created on edubuntu?

Tags: 14.04

I am new to ubuntu, I recently set up an edubuntu ltsp 14.04 server. I manually assigned disk quota limit to already existing users. Is there a way to make the server automatically assign quota limit to new users as they are being created? maybe a script or something? 
Help is really needed here...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of assigning the quota to every user you could assign the quota to a group.
Then simply add the new users to this group when you create them.

Comment: okay, so this automatically assigns the group quota to the new users?

Comment: Yes, but this way you can only set the qutoa for the whole group, not the specific user.  You could write a script that checks if new users are created and then adds the quota for them. But just adding them by hand when creating the user seems simpler and doesn`t take much time, it`s just one command.

Comment: alright,thanks alot. can you also please help me with a script that does that, just incase i have to end up doing it?

Comment: Can't write that script from the top of my head. It`s easier just to add/copy the quote when you create a user. Also reffer to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/disk_quota#Copying_quota_settings)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Quota for the group is not the same as quota for each user in the group.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can have this set.  Edit /etc/adduser.conf and add 'QUOTAUSER={user}' where {user} is set to either a user that you want to clone quota settings from, or a generic account with quota defined.  See 'man adduser.conf' for more info.